# how to set "Build after other projects are built" and "Poll SCM" simultaneously in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have some jobs on Jenkins. One of them is related to database and I want it to be built just  when there is a change in its sub-version. Simultaneously, I want it to be built after another projects. To be more clear, consider I have two projects A and B and I want B to be built after successful build of A just if there is a change in B's sub-version. How to config that?

**EDIT 1:**

In case where I set build of some other project, i.e. C, to be triggered as a post build action in project B, there will be no build for C, if B has no SCM changes. How to solve this?

**EDIT 2:**

To clarify my question, I put it this way. I have some projects named A, B and C. I want to put them in a build queue because they depend to each other: A -> B -> C. But there are some considerations. B is a database project and it should be built just when there is any upgrade in the database, otherwise it will give me some errors. Besides, we have to build B before C, if there's any changes in the SCM of B; because it affects the functionality of project C. So, in simple words, I want Jenkins to follow these steps:

1. Build A.
2. Check the SCM of B.
3. If there is any changes in the SCM of B, build B, otherwise skip building B.
4. Build C.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did not get your question. Do you mean to say that you **do not** want C to be build if B has no SCM changes?

Comment: @Technext, could please review my edits in the question?

Comment: For job B, i hope when you say upgrade in the database, you are detecting the change using SCM (in your case, SVN), correct? Are detection of database upgrade and SCM change different things in job B?

Comment: Yes @Technext, you got right!

Comment: Just one 'Yes' for both the questions that i asked is contradicting each other. Please answer both the questions. Only then can i provide some help.

Comment: @Technext, I'm sorry if I was not clear. "Yes" was for first question. `upgrade in the database` equals to `change using SCM`. The answer of second question is no; there is no difference between `database upgrade` and `SCM change`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60392/discussion-between-technext-and-zeinab-abbasi).

Comment: @Technext, can we get back to our chat?

Comment: I am trying out something and will post once i'm done. Hopefully today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just take care of it **in** job B.

Have your workflow always trigger A -> B -> C.

Now in B job, use [**Conditional Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to run a script that will verify that B project has no SCM changes. If no changes, skip the build step and continue to triggering C. Else build B and continue to triggering C.

Answer (score 3):

[Downstream-Ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin) seems to do what you're looking for. I have not used it because i never felt the need for it. :)

Once you will install it, in your job's config page, go to `Post-build Actions > Build other projects (extended)`. Rest can be see from the snapshot below. I have specified my downstream job B, enabled check-box `Trigger only if downstream project has SCM changes` & selected *equal* in the build result drop-down because i want to trigger job B only if my parent job A always SUCCEEDS and if B has SCM (SVN, in your case) changes.

[image]

Comment: It was really useful, but I faced some other issues related to the subject. Could you please review the question?

Comment: I found the answer; please check Slav's answer. Thank you for giving me help.